# loading texture with openGL and C#

Tags: c#, tao-framework

hi
i'm trying to load a texture (.bmp image) ...

with debugging i see it has been loaded  ... but on the screen nothing appear!
here is my code :

```
int front_ID = Terrain.LoadGLTextures(@"C:\Users\Ruba\Desktop\our project graphic2\our project graphic\images\top.bmp");
        int back_ID = Terrain.LoadGLTextures(@"C:\Users\Ruba\Desktop\our project graphic2\our project graphic\images\top.bmp");
        int right_ID = Terrain.LoadGLTextures(@"C:\Users\Ruba\Desktop\our project graphic2\our project graphic\images\top.bmp");
        int left_ID = Terrain.LoadGLTextures(@"C:\Users\Ruba\Desktop\our project graphic2\our project graphic\images\top.bmp");
        int top_ID = Terrain.LoadGLTextures(@"C:\Users\Ruba\Desktop\our project graphic2\our project graphic\images\top.bmp");
        int down_ID = Terrain.LoadGLTextures(@"C:\Users\Ruba\Desktop\our project graphic2\our project graphic\images\top.bmp");

        Terrain.draw_skybox(520, front_ID, back_ID, right_ID, left_ID, top_ID, down_ID);
```

and the method (draw_skybox) :

```
public static void draw_skybox(float size, int front, int back, int right, int left, int up, int bottom)
    {
        float scale = 1; // important 

        Gl.glPushMatrix();

        Gl.glScalef(size, size, size);


        //Front Face
        //Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_CULL_FACE);
        Gl.glCullFace(Gl.GL_BACK);
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, front);

        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        Gl.glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glEnd();
        //Gl.glCullFace(Gl.GL_BACK);
        // Gl.glDisable(Gl.GL_CULL_FACE);
        //Back Face
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, back);
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        Gl.glNormal3f(0, 0, -1);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glEnd();

        //right face
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, right);
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        Gl.glNormal3f(1, 0, 0);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glEnd();

        //Left Face
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, left);
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        Gl.glNormal3f(-1, 0, 0);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glEnd();

        //Top Face
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, up);

        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        Gl.glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glEnd();


        //Bottom Face

        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, bottom);
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        Gl.glNormal3f(0, -1, 0);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glEnd();

        Gl.glPopMatrix();


    }


public static void draw_skybox(float size, int front, int back, int right, int left, int up, int bottom)
    {
        float scale = 1; // important 

        Gl.glPushMatrix();

        Gl.glScalef(size, size, size);


        //Front Face
        //Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_CULL_FACE);
        //Gl.glCullFace(Gl.GL_BACK);
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, front);

        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        Gl.glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glEnd();
        //Gl.glCullFace(Gl.GL_BACK);
        // Gl.glDisable(Gl.GL_CULL_FACE);
        //Back Face
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, back);
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        Gl.glNormal3f(0, 0, -1);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glEnd();

        //right face
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, right);
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        Gl.glNormal3f(1, 0, 0);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glEnd();

        //Left Face
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, left);
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        Gl.glNormal3f(-1, 0, 0);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glEnd();

        //Top Face
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, up);

        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        Gl.glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glEnd();


        //Bottom Face

        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, bottom);
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        Gl.glNormal3f(0, -1, 0);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        Gl.glEnd();

        Gl.glPopMatrix();


    }
```

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things you should check.

Is Texturing enabled?

```
Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Are you calling `Gl.glGenTextures(...)` and `Gl.glTexImage2D(...)` inside `Terrain.LoadGLTextures(...);` ?

The winding order of the back, right & bottom quads is wrong. The winding must be counter clock wise. Since you're enabling culling, those quads won't be seen from inside the cube volume. Just swap the first & second vertices, and the third & fourth.

Make sure you're viewing the scene from inside the volume.

Do you really want to use the Tao Framework? The Tao Framework hasn't been updated since may 2008 and is effectivaly defunct since july 2010. Perhaps you should take a look at the OpenTK Framework: http://www.opentk.com/

Comment: Have a look at these: http://www.opentk.com/doc/faq & http://www.opentk.com/doc/graphics/textures/loading